# What's the diffrence between _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp and _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$up in libdispatch.dylib?

Tags: ios, crash, comparison, grand-central-dispatch, variant

Looking through multiple iOS crash logs, I'm finding stack traces which are near identical with the one exception being the aforementioned line from libdispatch.dylib. I'm curious if this difference is meaningful (and as such, these crashes should be separated into different buckets) or if it is trivial. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's is the same function for all practical purposes, you can treat them as identical for crash aggregation, the difference is purely an internal implementation detail.